# Using nested bootstrap modal in Angular 2. How can I prevent Bootstrap Modal from disappearing when clicking outside

Tags: angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an angular project that uses 2 bootstrap modal components. The first modal is a form and while the other is just confirmation for the user if he/she wants to exit the form. I forked a plunker similar to my problem. What I want is to prevent the second model from closing when the user clicks outside the modal. I already tried adding this "data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"" to the second modal but it's not working.

```
<popup #modal1 data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
<div class="popup-header">
  Form
</div>
<div class="popup-body">
  Name
  <input type="text">
</div>
<div class="popup-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="modal2.show()">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</div>
```

```
<popup #modal2  data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
<div class="popup-header">
  Warning
</div>
<div class="popup-body">
  Are you sure you want to exit
</div>
<div class="popup-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="modal2.hide()">Cancel</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="modal2.hide() ; modal1.hide()">Close</button>
</div>
```

Here's the plunkr. https://plnkr.co/edit/hIinDea4XNVeJEkXTixW?p=preview

Comment: [config]="{backdrop: 'static'}"

Comment: Hi @JuliaPassynkova where should I placed that one. In the form component that uses it or should I place that in the confirmation modal.  I tried adding it to the confiramtion itself but it's not working.Can you check my plunker please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/U8gRRF9S2qZfzGUasFEK

1. Use HostListener from Angular to get event from host
2. Use Input param to configure you model
3. Consider to use ng2-boostrap library

   for second model:

   ```
   <popup #modal2 [isStatic]="'true'">
   ```

   for modal component:

   ```
   @Component({
   selector: 'popup',
   template: `
   <div class="modal fade"
   tabindex="-1" [ngClass]="{'in': visibleAnimate}"
        [ngStyle]="{'display': visible ? 'block' : 'none', 'opacity': visibleAnimate ? 1 : 0}">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
       <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
           <ng-content select=".popup-header"></ng-content>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
           <ng-content select=".popup-body"></ng-content>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
           <ng-content select=".popup-footer"></ng-content>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   `,
   styles: [`
     .modal {
       background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
     }
   `]
    })
    export class ModalComponent {
   @Input() isStatic : boolean;
   public visible = false;
   private visibleAnimate = false;

   constructor(){}

   public show(): void {
     this.visible = true;
     setTimeout(() => this.visibleAnimate = true, 100);
   }

   public hide(): void {
     this.visibleAnimate = false;
     setTimeout(() => this.visible = false, 300);
   }
   /*
   public onContainerClicked(event: MouseEvent): void {
     if ((<HTMLElement>event.target).classList.contains('modal')) {
       this.hide();
     }
   }*/


   @HostListener('click',  ['$event.target'])
   public onClick(target): void {
     if(target.classList.contains('modal')) {
       if(this.isStatic) {
         return;
       }
       else {
          this.hide();
       }
     }
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: I have a question how can I control the show and hide of modal component in the ts/typescript of the form component. As for your example the trigger of show and hide is in the template. I want it to be controlled in the ts.

Comment: do u mean from AppComponent component? use @ViewChildren to access popup components and call methods on it to control

Comment: I already done it @JuliaPassynkova. Anyway thanks for your help :)

Comment: I know this is too much hehe but can I message you outside stackoverflow? I really have a lot questions about angular.  I'm now working on a angular 2 project with java on the back-end. I just saw your profile that you also have an experience in java. I really want to ask a lot to you. :)

Comment: Hi @JuliaPassynkova. I have another question related to this. Your solution really works on chrome and firefox but when I tried running it on IE it doesn't work. Do you have any suggestion how can I run it on IE?. Thank you so much for always answering my question :)

Comment: sorry i do not have experience with IE and Angular 2. what exception? what is not working?

Comment: ok, i will look today evening when i get access to windows ;-). sorry i am mac user.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import modal js to make it work. Your plunker only has CSS imported.

I would recommend you to use another control instead. Here is how to intercept hide event.

```
$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal',function(e){
    if (...) { // put your own logic here.
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent modal from being closed.
    }
}).modal();
```

Or use backdrop:

```
$('#myModal').modal({backdrop:'static'});
```